# Which version of clockwork recovery creates backups as a tar files?

Tags: backup, clockworkmod-recovery

I have used several versions of CWM recovery on my Motorola Droid 2.
One of them was able to back up into a `.tar` (`cache.ext3.tar`, `data.ext3.tar` `nandroid.md5`, `recovery.img`, `system.ext3.tar`) as opposed to the `.img` files that I am getting now.

Now I can't seem to find that version anymore; can someone tell me which version was able to do that?

(Currently running v5.0.2.0 from http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no incompatibility for backups/restores between CWM versions 2.x, 3.x and 4.x.
 Both the filenames and the contents of the backup files will be the same.

With the CWM version 5.x:

- It can read and restore the backup files created by all the older versions of CWM.
- If you create a backup with 5.x, an try to restore it in one of the older CWM versions, two issues come up:

  1. File formats:

     The contents of `/data` and `/sdcard/.android_secure` are now in tar files instead of the old yaffs2 image files.
  2. Filenames:

     The backup filenames have changed from `partition_name.img` to `partition_name.fstype.ext`.

---

**To answer your question:**

Since you have files like the `partition_name.fstype.ext`, they refer to a backup from the CWM version 5.x.

**e.g.,** your file `system.ext3.tar` is from the partition `system`, using file system `ext3` and backed up within a `.tar` file.

Comment: Yeah, i have 5.0.2.0 so I should expect it to be backed up as .tar then? I'm still getting .img

Comment: @arcyqwerty There's a method to allow 5.x performing backups using the old file name and format. Have you altered any configuration for CWM related to backups?

Comment: I don't think so?
I'll look into it. I just reflashed so perhaps putting CWM on again will fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

it is "CWM-Lotus V6.0.4.7"
have a nice day :)

Comment: Welcome to [android.se]. Thank you for your contribution, but could you provide official reference, if it exists?